# UIBarButton won't show in my UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I want to make a simple view with a navigation bar and a table view. So I created a subclass of `UINavigationController` and I added a `UITableView` in it. My is is also the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Now I want to add `UIBarButton` in the navigation bar but it doesn't work :

```
UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:[[Translator instance] getTranslation:@"Back"] 
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                                 target:self.parentViewController  
                                                                 action:@selector(dismissFiltersModal:)];          
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
```

There's no error the view is displayed but not the button. How can I do to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jafar,

as Apple doc suggested you should avoid to subclass `UINavigationController`.

> This class is not intended for subclassing.

Said this, you could follow these simply steps (some advice for you):

- Create your controller (say `MyController`) that extends `UIViewController` and add the table here. Set your controller as the delegate and data source for that table. If you have created by xib you need an outlet for your table view.

[**P.S**. you could also subclass a `UITableViewController`, it has a table view its own]

- In `viewDidLoad` of `MyController` customize the navigation bar.

For example

```
UIBarButtonItem* myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(someSelector)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myButton;
```

You could also customize the title.

For example

```
self.title = @"Your custom title";
```

- Somewhere in your code create a `UINavigationController` and add as a root view controller an instance of `MyController`.

For example:

```
MyController* myCtr = // alloc-init here
UINavigationController* nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myCtr];
```

Comment: great it works :) Since I present that view as a modal view is there a provided way to keep caller reference inside MyController ? Because if I use self.parentViewController it references the UINavigationController nc and not the object from where I presented the modal view (which is normal I guess).

Answer (score 1):

The `backBarButtonItem` should be set on the previous view controller, not the current one to be displayed. For example, if your you are on view A, navigate to B from it, inside B A's `backBarButtonItem` will be displayed, *not* B's.

If you just want to display an item on the left hand side of the navigation bar, you can use `leftBarButtonItem` instead, which will display a normal bar button on that controller. It will be rectangular, not an arrow like normal back buttons though.

Answer (score 1):

How about you try this :

```
UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; // left-pointing shape!
        [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissFiltersModal:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// create button item -- 
UIBarButtonItem* backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

// add to toolbar
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem;
```

Comment: I tried this but the button has not a left-pointing shape. The text is just a little shifted to the right :/